# Do windows symbols files need to be exactly matched

Tags: windows-xp, windbg, debug-symbols

I have windows xp that already up-to-date, and I have downloaded Microsoft Symbols for Windows SP3. Can I use it with my XP? I don't have access to the original disc

Also I found original XP SP3 ISO here ftp://t1subnet-233-68.ideaone.net/ should I use that image instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother downloading the complete symbols pack. Just point WinDbg to MS symbols server, and it will download the appropriate symbols, when they are needed.

Read: [Use the Microsoft Symbol Server to obtain debug symbol files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503).